# Iterate all files of specific extension while avoiding symlinks

Tags: c#, windows, parsing, symlink

I want to have a list of fullpath of all files containg any extension of the extensions list.
The code snippet below works fine if I run it on desktop or download folder. But in Documents, it will fail because that folder contains several symlink and I'm getting an access denied when it tries to enter these "folders".
How can I tell my code to simply ignore this exception and continue looping?

```cs
var extensions = new List<string> { ".doc", ".docx", ".xls" };
try
{
    string[] desktop = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Documents", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(f => extensions.IndexOf(Path.GetExtension(f)) >= 0).ToArray();
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: I have two articles about exception handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | This is a good case for either a Exogenous or Vexing exception. As with the file example, this is not something you can reliably test as it might change between test and execution. It might be best to simply expect "AcessDenied" and continue afterwards. Definitely note the file, but go on.

Comment: FYI, if you're talking about the "My Music", "My Pictures", and "My Videos" junctions, those are mount points, which are roughly equivalent to a Unix "bind" mount in this case. There are several things that set mount points and symlinks apart, and one aspect in particular in Windows is that the security descriptor of a mount point is evaluated in addition to the security of its target. In these cases, the junctions have a deny entry that prevents everyone from listing the directory. They're allowed to be traversed, however, even without SeChangeNotifyPrivilege.

Comment: It can become even more fun when you try and access a file and it says it is locked.  At first you may look for an IsLocked() function.  But even if there was one, who is to say that immediately after calling it, the file gets locked before you access it.  In that case you need to use an Exception handler.  It's the only scenario I have ever found where the Exception is not an error it is part of the actual code.